# What is the Latin etymon of 'que' in the French « ne ... que »?

Tags: etymology, french

I am still trying to understand the etymology of the French adverbial ['ne que'](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/14160/1995), and so researched the Latin etymons of these two Functional Morphemes for more sapience.
This question concerns only the meaning in V and VII below.

> [ [Wiktionary in French](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/que#.C3.89tymologie) :] I. (Conjonction 1) Du latin [quia](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/quia#la), qui exprime la cause.
>   II. (Conjonction 2) Du latin [quam](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/quam#la).
>   III. (Pronom relatif) Du latin [qui](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/qui#la), [quae](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/quae#la), [quod](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/quod#la) ; dans l’ancien français, *que* devint la forme atone du [cas régime](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/cas_r%C3%A9gime), sans distinction de genre ni de nombre.
>   IV. (Pronom interrogatif) Du latin [quid](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/quid#la).
>
> [...]  [ V. [Adverbe 2 :](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/que#Adverbe_2) ] Personne excepté, rien excepté. Seulement. Utilisé avec [ne](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/ne#fr-part).
>
> [...]  [ VI. [Etymology 1 :](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/que#Etymology_1_2) ] From Latin [quia](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/quia#Latin).
>
> **Conjunction
>
>   que**   [...]
>
> [VII.] 2. (used with [*ne*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ne#French)) only
>    (n*e ... que*   parses roughly as   "(do[es]) not / nothing ... other than")

Somewhere is at least 1 error, because English Wiktionary classifies 'que' as a Conjunction, but French Wiktionary an adverb.

Anyhow, which is the Latin etymon of the French *que*?

Comment: I think the structure people would use in Latin is *nihil nisi*. For example, "I eat nothing but cheese" is *nihil edo nisi caseum*. Would that be "je ne mange que du fromage" in French? My French is rusty, so I want to check that I understand the "ne-que" correctly.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta: Yup, *nisi* is a good translation. But the Romans could also express *nothing but* as *nothing other than*: *nihil aliud quam*.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta Yes: your French translation is correct! I defer to others though for the Latin.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would seem logical to me if it came from *quam*. The [Trésor de la langue française](http://circe.atilf.fr/definition/que) does not explain its exact origin, but it does give the meaning of *ne ... que* as "ne ... rien d'autre que". And *other than* is often expressed as *aliud quam* in Latin. The Tlf groups *ne ... que* under that subsense of *que* which is a conjunction of comparison, like *plus que, mieux que*, which works the same way in Latin: *plus quam, melius quam*. The Tlf mentions that the conjunction *que* "that", from *quia*, was at some point confused with the conjunction *quam* (which probably also sounded somewhat like *que* by then?), especially with comparatives:

> D'autre part, à basse époque, *quia* s'affaiblit progressivement en *qua* devant consonne init. et *qui* devant voyelle; ces deux formes s'étant par la suite, empl. indistinctement, *qua* se localisa notamment en Italie du Nord et du Sud, et *qui* en Italie centrale, dans le domaine ibéro-roman et dans le domaine gallo-rom. où il est relevé au viiie s. sous la forme *que*. **Cette forme favorise sa confusion avec** le rel. *quem*, cas régime (*que* rel.) et **la conj. *quam*, spéc. dans son empl. en corrélation avec un compar.** (ixe s.), v. FEW t. 2, 1466ab et J. Herman, op. cit., pp. 125-129.